# count columns from externat stage on snowflake

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, google-bucket

I'm ussing snowflake flake to create a data warehouse. and i puted scripte to let data updated.

the data is stored on GCP bucket (external stage). So that i can control if the data is updated correctlly or not i'm traying to  compare between rows (sonwflake/stage) and columns number (snowflake/stage or bucket)

for the rows; it's okey.
But i could'nt count columns from the stage or gcp bucket to comparat and see if all data is loaded correctly.

can you help! if you have some idea to how can i  get number of columns from stage or GCP Bucket

Thank u ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may check out this post to count columns in the CSV file: [How can I get number of columns in Staged File Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64161800/how-can-i-get-number-of-columns-in-staged-file-snowflake)

For a concrete example, it depends on your file structure. Can you share an example please?

Comment: Okey, So for the structur it the same form all csv files but number of column is not tha same. 
and for the momnet i'm trying to creat a procedure that i will call with parameters to compare
Found below a small example of file's structure 

PS: The first row contain name of columns

a | b | c
1 | 2 | 3
8 | 7 | 7